# Create symbolic links from list of files

Tags: bash, shell

I have a folder which contains multiple files and one file (`file_list`), which lists the files of interest. I want to create symbolic links to all files that match the file names in the list. Is there an easy way to do this in bash?

Example:

- Folder contains: `file1`, `file2`, `file3`, `file4`, `file5`
- Contents of `file_list`: `file1, file3, file5`
- Destination folder should contain: Symbolic links for `file1`, `file3` and `file5`

Comment: What did you try till now?

Comment: @tukan I looked at the help page for "ln", but as I understand I need to use some other command and pipe it into the ln command, but as to what commands that is I have no idea. I have tried a bit in R, but want to find a solution in bash for simplicity

Comment: What I meant by that is that you should try it on your own (you will learn much more that way too).  If you fail you should come to help.  Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should do:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash 

while IFS= read -r file; do
    [[ -e /some/path/$file ]] && ln -s "/some/path/$file" /dest/path
done < file_list
```

Comment: Thanks! Tried the script, changed the paths to the file directories, and set the destination path, and also specified the file_list location, but it didn't create any links in the specified directory. Any ideas?

Comment: @Haakonkas Did you get any errors? Are you sure the paths are correct?

Comment: Got no errors, it just ran without producing any links. I am sure that the file paths are correct, but unsure if the correct paths are in the correct place in the script. ```-e some/path/$file``` and ```ln -s "some/path/$file"``` is the folder where all the files are (both the wanted and unwanted ones)? And file_list is the text file with the filenames?

Comment: @Haakonkas yep, `/some/path` is the path to the source folder. Use absolute path to be sure. Are there any filenames in `file_list` that actually correspond to real names inside `/some/path`?

Comment: Yes, the filenames in the file directly match some of the files in the folder (i created the list in R using list.files() and matching to a vector with filenames of interest).

Comment: @Haakonkas Please edit your Q and post the actual content of `file_list` as it is now.

Comment: I managed to get it to work now, it was an issue with the file_list from the beginning. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work as `cp -s` makes symbolic links

```bash
cp -s $(cat file_list) /path/to/destination/dir/
```